# EPPlus crashed my api in AWS Linux ECS

Tags: .net-core, epplus

I have a web api that I upload Excel files to then import the sheets into a sql table.  This works fine when I run it standalone on windows, but in an AWS ECS (Docker container) it crashes the task when I call new ExcelPackage(fs) where fs is a stream from S3.

There are no logs of any help - it just dies a sudden and horrible death.

Anyone else seen this?  Maybe there is something else I can use to read Excel files (XSLX).

Im using .Net Core 2.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the super helpful down vote.  Maybe it would be more useful to tell me what's wrong with my question so I can fix it?  Anyways.. I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using ExcelDataReader (https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) instead of EPPlus and it works just fine.  In fact I think it's faster, plus it also support XLS files.

Part of the document for ExcelDataReader does mention adding a text encoding provider (System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider) that is not added by default in .Net Core so that may have also been the problem with EPPlus.